# Method for returning even numbers

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, int

This method will not compile, can't see why. Error is:

> Can't find symbol-variable i

The `int i` is defined in the for-loop. The method should return the even numbers between `int a` and `int b`.

The code:

```
public int partall(int a, int b){
    int partall;
    int største; 
    int minste;
    if(a == b){
        partall = 0;
    }else{
        if(a>b) {
        største = a;
        minste = b; 
        }else if(a<b){
            minste = a;
            største = b;

            for(int i = minste;  i<= største; i++){
                if(i % 2 == 0) {
                     partall = i;
                }
            }

        }

    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: `i` is only visible in the scope of the loop, because that's where it's declared. Declare `i` inside the method and it will be visible in the `return` statement.

Comment: We have tried writing int i under int minste and we still got the error.

Comment: The same error or a different one?

Comment: Read my solution below. The new error you got after adding i was because you then need to initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `i` which has scope only in `for loop` not outside that.

From the implementation, I think you might probably want to return `partall` but not `i`.

Initialize `partall` with something, i.e.

`int partall = 0;`

and in the last line

`return partall;`

That should work

Comment: Thank you, this work like a charm

Answer (score 2):

`i` is only visible in the scope of `for` loop, but not outside. When you do `return i;` it is out of scope. So you need to put the declaration outside of `for` block.

**Solution:**

```
public int partall(int a, int b){
    int partall;
    int største; 
    int minste;
    int i = 0; 
    if(a == b){
        partall = 0;
    }else{
        if(a>b) {
            største = a;
            minste = b; 
        }else if(a<b){
            minste = a;
            største = b;

            for(i = minste;  i<= største; i++){
                if(i % 2 == 0) {
                    partall = i;
                }
            }

        }

    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately we still got the same error saying that int i is not defined

Comment: @Akarlsen you need to re-compile your code after making the changes. It might be picking the old .class file

Comment: No, this does produce a compilation error due to i potentially not being initialized. It needs to be initialized to a value.

Comment: @MaxWeinzierl Now I updated the answer so it is always initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `i` is not visible in the scope of the `return` statement. You need to declare `i` outside of the `for` loop and outside of the `if-else` for it to be visible in the scope of the `return`. Try declaring `int i = 0;` (or even `int i = minste;` and remove the assignment below) at the top of the function where you declare the rest of your variables.

Answer (score 0):

you should initialize "partall" and return that variable:

```
public int partall(int a, int b){
    int partall = 0;
    int største; 
    int minste;
    if(a == b){
        partall = 0;
    }else {
        if(a>b) {
        største = a;
        minste = b; 
    } else if(a<b) {
        minste = a;
        største = b;

    for(int i = minste;  i<= største; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            partall = i;
        }
    }

   }

}
return partall;
```

}